# How do I increase speed every time I kill an enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so that every time I kill an enemy, my player's speed increases by 1. I've been trying to do this but I don't really know what I'm doing. Can somebody help me?

Here is my player movement script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 5;
    public float JumpForce = 5;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Movement
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Enemy script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public int health = 100;
    private static float speed;
    private static float jump;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
            speed += 1.0f;
            jump += 1.0f;
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        speed = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed;
        jump = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce;
    }
}
```

Sorry, my question didn't have all the details, the player is not gaining any speed. I tried using

```
GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed += 1.0f;
GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce += 1.0f;
```

and now I'm getting this error message

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It seems counterintuitive that an enemy would have a `PlayerMovement` component  on it. Consider finding a way to let the player know it killed something. It isn't clear how the `TakeDamage` function is called, but assuming it is called by the player you could return a value to indicate a death. Perhaps true == death, false == just damage.

Comment: Is there only one player in your scene?

Comment: @derHugo there is 1 player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it makes no sense to use `GetComponent` since the `PlayerMovement` is not attached to your enemy objects.

Then

```
speed = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed;
jump = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce
```

is also the wrong way round .. what use would it be to take the value from the player and store it in a field of the enemy?

If there is only one player anyway you could simply use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) and do

```
void Die()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed += 1.0f;
    FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce += 1.0f;
}
```

---

Or alternatively use a Singleton Pattern as actually even suggested by before mentioned docs like e.g.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerMovement Instance { get; private set;}

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(Instance && Instance!= this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Instance = this;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then simply do

```
void Die()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    PlayerMovement.Instance.MovementSpeed += 1.0f;
    PlayerMovement.Instance.JumpForce += 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to increase the jumpforce and speed of your player when the player kills an enemy. Also, Could you please elaborate the question if you are getting any error or just the speed is not increasing?

Please find the inline response for the Enemy Script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public int health = 100;
private static float speed;//This is enemy speed variable that you have declared
private static float jump;//This is enemy jump variable that you have declared

public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    health -= damage;

    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Die();
        //speed += 1.0f; Here you are increasing enemy speed and not playerspeed.
        //jump += 1.0f; Same goes for jump.
    }
}

void Die()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    //speed = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed; here you are assigning Player movement speed to enemy speed.
    //jump = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce; here you are assigning Player movement jump to enemy jump.

//Instead try
GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().MovementSpeed += 1.0f;
GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().JumpForce += 1.0f;

}
}
```

Also you can use

> Debug.Log(your movementspeed variable);

to check if the player speed is being increased or not.

Comment: Why would the `PlayerMovement` component be attached to the enemy?

Comment: @derHugo I assumed that he wanted to increase player speed when an enemy dies, and I dont know how the takeDamage() function is called by him.

Comment: Still makes no sense to use `GetComponent` on the enemy object .. the same one you Destroy one line before

Comment: @derHugo Oh, sorry I am also learning Unity, I didn't think in terms of enemy object getting destroyed. if you could explain a better approach it would be much appreciated. Thanks again